# Docker django runs only if I specify the command

Tags: django, docker, dockerfile

I am new to docker and I was trying to create an Image for my Django application. 
I have created the image using the following Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN pip install -r Requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "manage.py"]

CMD ["runserver", '0.0.0.0:8000']
```

The problem is when I run the image using
`docker run -p 8000:8000 <image-tag>`

I am unable to access the app in my localhost:8000

But if I run the container using the command
`docker run -p 8000:8000 <image-tag> runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

I can see my app in localhost:8000

Comment: What happens if you do run the first command?  (Do you get any error messages or output from Django?). Does it help to change the single quotes to double quotes in the `CMD`?

Comment: @DavidMaze there are no errors, the container runs but I am not able to access the app. Changing to double or single quotes makes no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can use only Entrypoint command.
Try with:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN pip install -r Requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Or you can write script file (entrypoint.sh) with the line. And maybe you can run makemigrations and migrations in the same file.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Can you explain me why does this work and my approach does not ?

Comment: Yes, you can see here https://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/ the difference between cmd and entrypoint. You can use one of them, depends on if you needs that run on exec command, or not. The difference between your code and my code, is that I use only one line, the command and parameters as array of strings. Your code execute two commands, python manage.py, and runserver ip:port at next line

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the single quotes to double quotes in your `CMD` line.

Let's play with this simplified Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine
ENTRYPOINT ["echo", "python", "manage.py"]
CMD ["runserver", '0.0.0.0:8000']
```

Now build it and run it:

```
$ docker build .
...
Successfully built 24d598ae4182
$ docker run --rm 24d598ae4182
python manage.py /bin/sh -c ["runserver", '0.0.0.0:8000']
```

Docker is pretty picky on the JSON-array form of the `CMD`, `ENTRYPOINT`, and `RUN` commands.  If something doesn't parse as a JSON array, it will silently fall back to treating it as a plain command, which will get implicitly wrapped in a `/bin/sh -c '...'` invocation.  That's what you're seeing here.

If you edit my Dockerfile to have double quotes in the `CMD` line and rebuild the image, then you'll see

```
$ docker run --rm 58114fa1fdb4
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

and if you actually `COPY` code in, use a Python base image, and delete that debugging `echo`, that's the command you want to execute.